# Javascript slideshow gallery that doesn't use a wrapper element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, slideshow

I am looking for a JavaScript/jQuery slider library that uses swipe gestures on mobile and desktop, but also supports manual slide change (with buttons).

The biggest condition: that the library doesn't wrap my slide elements in an extra wrapper since i'm implementing it into a WYSIWYG website editor. Would be great if it was clever enough to apply transitions on each slide instead on the wrapper element.

Good examples of what i need (sadly though with an extra wrapper `DIV`): 
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Answer (score 0):

I use jssor is a good plugin jquery slider.